# Is it possible, in C, to write in one line a call to a function that has an array of strings (ie ptr) or int, or ... as parameter?

Tags: arrays, c, parameters, arguments, function-call

Let's consider these two functions :

```
void my_foo1(char ** my_par, int size) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) printf("%s \n",my_par[i]);
}

void my_foo2(int * my_par, int size) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) printf("%d \n",my_par[i]);
}
```

To call them, variables are declared and initialized. And after, function are called on a second line with these variables.

```
char * (my_strs[3])={"hello","world","!!!!"};
my_foo1(my_strs,3);

int my_ints[3]={1,2,3};
my_foo2(my_ints,3);
```

Is it possible to write something like :

```
my_foox(????,3)
```

and avoid the variable declaration ?

Comment: Are you aiming to _change_ the values in the arrays in your functions? If not, make them `const char/int **`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like what you're looking for is a *compound literal*:

```
my_foo1((char *[]){"hello","world","!!!!"},3);
my_foo2((int []){1,2,3},3);
```

Note that such literals have the lifetime of their enclosing scope.

Comment: Note however that this approach does not enforce consistency between the array length and the `size` function argument, whereas this would: `char *my_strs[] = { "hello", "world", "!!!!" }; my_foo1(my_strs, sizeof(my_strs) / sizeof(*my_strs));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use compound literals as for example

```
void my_foo2(int * my_par, int size) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) printf("%d \n",my_par[i]);
}

my_foo2( ( int [] ){ 1, 2, 3 }, 3 );
```

In the call of the function `foo2` the compound literal having the type `int[3]` is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `int *` to its first element.

Pay attention to as the function does not change the passed array then it will be better to declare it like

```
void my_foo2( const int * my_par, int size) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) printf("%d \n",my_par[i]);
}
```